# Json Serealize / Deserialize

Tags: c#, json

подскажите пожалуйста. Как можно записать json вот так ?

```
{
  "Date": "2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
  "TemperatureCelsius": 25,
  "Summary": "Hot",
  "DatesAvailable": [
    "2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
    "2019-08-02T00:00:00-07:00"
  ],
  "TemperatureRanges": {
                "Cold": {
                    "High": 20,
      "Low": -10
                },
    "Hot": {
                    ""High": 60,
      "Low": 20
    }
            },
  "SummaryWords": [
    "Cool",
    "Windy",
    "Humid"
  ]
}
```

А так же его прочитать? Сколько искал информации в гугле - ничего понятного для меня я не нашел.
Буду рад тем кто подскажет.

Comment: Зачем двойные кавычки? Разве такое разрешено стандартом JSON?

Comment: Так не разрешено.

Comment: Экранируйте слышами так `\"` и все будет хорошо

Comment: Кроме двойной кавычки (что я считаю опечаткой с вашей стороны), тут других проблем нету, простая структура классов, не более. Так что, возникает вопрос - где ваши попытки решения этой задачи? Или вы пытались найти именно под вашу структуру решения, не разбираясь как работает сам JSON? Ну чтож, все просто: `"Name": value` - это свойство (`public string Name {get;set;}`) например. `{ ... }` - класс, содержащий в себе свойства. Ну а `[ ... ]` - простой массив/коллекция.

Answer (score 0):

Есть удобный [сайт](https://json2csharp.com/) для конвертирования JSON в C#

Это будет выглядеть так:

```
// Создание объекта
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

    public class Cold
    {
        public int High { get; set; }
        public int Low { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hot
    {
        public int High { get; set; }
        public int Low { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public List<DateTime> DatesAvailable { get; set; }
        public TemperatureRanges TemperatureRanges { get; set; }
        public List<string> SummaryWords { get; set; }
    }

    public class TemperatureRanges
    {
        public Cold Cold { get; set; }
        public Hot Hot { get; set; }
    }
```